Unexcepted Behavior using PopScope Flutter Widget
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/home',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return switch (settings.name) {
          '/two' => MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => const PageTwo(),
            ),
          _ => MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => const PageOne(),
            ),
        };
      },
    );
  }
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageOne({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: const Text('Page One'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/two');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageTwo({super.key});

  @override
  State<PageTwo> createState() => _PageTwoState();
}

class _PageTwoState extends State<PageTwo> {
  Future<bool?> _showBackDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
        content: const Text(
          'Are you sure you want to leave this page?',
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Never Mind'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, false);
            },
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('leave'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, true);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: PopScope(
          canPop: false,
          onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
            if (didPop) {
              return;
            }
            final bool shouldPop = await _showBackDialog(context) ?? false;
            if (context.mounted && shouldPop) {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          },
          child: TextButton(
            child: const Text('Page Two'),
            onPressed: () async {
              final bool shouldPop = await _showBackDialog(context) ?? false;
              if (context.mounted && shouldPop) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}





So, Above I paste the entire code for the flutter PopScope.
I read the docs  and understand that it manages back navigation gestures.
So, I wanted to use this feature in my app whenever like when going back will destroy the state then i re-inform this feature. Even I was thinking when person tries to close my application then also I wanted to use this feature.
I was excepting to be when press back button in android phone then it will automatically run the _showDialogBox()  but rather it was giving me white screen

I was excepting the same result that i was getting when I pressed the second Screen Button but while using the gesture or back button and cause of got a weird white screen

I ran your code and it runs as expected on Android emulator API 35, built with Flutter 3.22.2.
Which Android API and Flutter versions do you use?
I can suggest running flutter clean and building from scratch to make sure.
The white screen may indicate over-popping the route - when you pop your top screen. This didn't happen in my test. I tried both the back button and swipe gesture.

@zysoft I am using Flutter 3.16.9 and Android API 34.

@zysoft can you confirm one more time, that you ran this code with gesture and back button it works? Please check in 3.16.9

yes, I can confirm I tried and it works for me.
Environment: Flutter 3.16.9, Dart 3.2.6, DevTools 2.28.5, Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1, Emulator API 34 arm64-v8a, macOS 14.5 (23F79).

@zysoft thanks buddy, It still not working in me, I will check again what the issue is.

if you're not hardly dependent on 3.16.9 I suggest upgrading - maybe that helps. It may be a combination of factors.
